# Algorithms : Master Theorem

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, master-theorem

Master theorem can be used to solve recurrence relations like
`T(n)= aT(n/b)+f(n)`.

So, if `f(n)=O(n)` or if `f(n)=cn` are both the values same?
can I use master theorem for `f(n)=cn` also?

Comment: Constants such as `c` are often ignored when considering asymptotic relations. This is because as `n` becomes sufficiently large, the constant makes it very hard to calculate memory consumption and running time.This would mean that `f(n)=n`, which is equivalent to `f(n)=O(n)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asumming that `c` is a constant and that I understand your question correctly, the solution will be the same for both `f(n) = O(n)` and `f(n) = cn`, since `cn = O(n)` and thus the Master theorem can be applied to solve the recurrance.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question correctly, `f(n)=cn` (where `c` is a constant) is in `O(n)`; the master theorem can be applied.